# Illustrator - Move anchor points while preserving angle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, anchor-point

I want to move an anchor point along its current path - I mean moving anchor points keeping their current angle. Look at this picture:

[image: diagram showing anchor point moving along its tangent direction]

According to above picture, let's say we want to move anchor point 1, but as you can see there is no option (or I cant find the option) to do this while preserving the angle - with the shift key, the anchor point snaps to 45° angles...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Illustrator does not have a easy shortcut to do this. However, you can do this with the **scale tool**. While this sounds as a weird thing, why it works becomes apparent once you realize we move the pivot point to previous control point. Here is what you do:

1. (Make sure smart guides is on)
2. Select the point you want to move.
3. Activate scale tool (<kbd>S</kbd>)
4. Move the anchor point to the position of prevous point
5. Drag aloing the direction, a indication uniform should be present and snap while you are dragging in right driection.

Answer (score 10):

There is also another way to do this with Smart Guides.

If you add a couple of anchors somewhat down a bit from the curve anchors (added anchors circled in red below), and convert those to corner points, then you can use the smart guides and it will show a Line Extension guide as you click and drag.

[image: Screenshot of Smart Guides]

Answer (score 3):

There is a (paid) plug-In from ASTUTE for this. It's called [VectorScribe](https://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/) and can do much much more. The function you are searching for calls trim and extend Paths. With this plug-in you may also move Anchor points without changing the Path.

You can use the free trial first or wait for special sales / discount.

Answer (score 3):

Hard worker's method:

- split your line segment with the 'Scissors' tool
- select the separated part and drag it longer with holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- select both parts and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> to join these

*Note due the comment: If you do not want an extra control point, do the splitting at an existing control point (=3 in your image)*

Comment: (4. and delete extra control point) Actually you can just click alt drag on the segment without the split, i sometimes do this.